# Plots made with rpy sent to X11 suddenly close?

Tags: python, x11, graphing, rpy2

I'm using RPy2 to make some plots. The plot shows up but the X11 window immediately disappears.

All I'm typing is the following, where *CCFS* is a data matrix

```
 import rpy2.robjects as robjects
 r = robjects.r

 pca = r.princomp(CCFS)
 r.plot(pca,main="Eigenvalues")
 r.biplot(pca,main="biplot")
 r['dev.off']() #*EDIT* the problem persists even if I remove this line.
```

Am I failing to include something? I know that there is something to plot because princomp returns a  ListVector that isn't null.

Comment: Are you doing this at an interactive prompt?  If so, try not issuing that last `'dev.off'` operation.

Comment: I did and it changes nothing. The plot does show up but then it closes. I'll add an x11 tag.

Comment: No, this is in a Python module.

Comment: OK, then it's probably going away because the program has exited.  You need the program to keep running until you're done, or else you need to use a batch-mode device like `pdf` or `png`.

Comment: Hmmm. I already have X11 running for something else (SSH forwarding, if that's important.) So, I'm sure that X11 doesn't close.

Comment: The X server keeps running, sure, but when the *Python script* terminates, all windows it has opened are automatically closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
input()         # for Python3
# raw_input()   # for Python2
```

to the end of the script to prevent the program from ending until the user presses Enter.

Comment: This works! However, it doesn't explain why the X11 window doesn't persist. For instance, the example RPy biplot script doesn't use this so I think I'm missing a bigger point.

Comment: When the `r` object is garbage collected, it apparently closes any window that it has created. I don't know what biplot script you are referring to, but if it was from documentation, it might just be showing the important bits, assuming you either know about `raw_input()` or that you'd use the code in a larger script that doesn't happen to end there.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I don't use RPy for any thing else in the script after the biplot line. So, of course, a smart garbage collector would close all windows right there. As if that's not enough, the Python script also ends right there. As @Zack noted, that would kill the X11 window even if it survived the garbage collector. Thanks- it makes sense now.

Comment: "raw_input" is renamed to "input" in Python 3, but this trick is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

As Zack pointed it out calling `dev.off()` on interactive graphical devices will just cause the device to close (and what it displays to disappear). On the other hand, closing non-interactive devices is mostly required before the plot can be checked (See [rpy2's documentation on graphical devices](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/graphics.html#graphical-devices)).

I am guessing that your Python code is called as a standalone program / script rather than part of an interactive Python session. In other words I am suspecting that you are having something like `python myscript.py` in a shell (the content of `myscript.py` being your code above); when the script ends the embedded R is obviously terminated, taking with it the interactive plot. This is likely also what Zack is thinking. Try `python -i myscript.py`, and then once in the Python console `import sys; sys.exit(0)` to see that exiting Python means closing R interactive devices.

Comment: You're right. I'm used to the Matplotlib functionality where the script stops until you close the plot, even if you generate the plot from a standalone script.

Comment: Customizing R devices to behave this way through rpy2 might be possible in the future (e.g., http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/graphicaldevices.html#rpy2.rinterface._rpy_device.GraphicalDevice.close). However, that's not yet the case.