# Plot shows up and disappears fast in R

Tags: python, r, numpy, plot

I am plotting some graphs using R. When I run the program the plot appears and then quickly disappears. How can I make the plot stay?`

I am running the following code found in [Dynamic Time Warping in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695388/dynamic-time-warping-in-python)

```
import numpy as np

import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

# Set up our R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

# Generate our data
idx = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
template = np.cos(idx)
query = np.sin(idx) + np.array(R.runif(100))/10

# Calculate the alignment vector and corresponding distance
alignment = R.dtw(query, template, keep=True)4
plot(alignments)
dist = alignment.rx('distance')[0][0]

print(dist)
```

Basically the main file is in python, I have installed rpy2, i am remotely connecting into a unix machine. Now the plot shows up but immediately disappears. This only happens to R plots. When I run matplotlib plots they stay(not disappear). so I am wondering whether I have to put some line of code to make the plots "stay". For example like the matlab "holdon".

Comment: Please produce a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  Be sure to explain how you're running the code.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269

Comment: using `x11()` before plotting in `R` should work.

Comment: thanks..that gives me a general direction. But what's the code for including x11()? ..........I am asking this because other libraries that I use within the same code (matplotlib) uses the X windowing system and doesn't require any explicit code snippets.

Comment: hmm I found this stackoverflow post very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655771/plots-made-with-rpy-sent-to-x11-suddenly-close

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to wait for the user to type "enter" before the program finishes:

```
raw_input("Please type enter...")
```

This is also useful with my Matplotlib plots (instead of using `pyplot.show()`: this closes all the plots automatically).

PS: I just saw that this was suggested in the link from the comments to the original question. I approve. :)