# How to display a heatmap created in python using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, quartz-graphics, rpy2

I am currently trying to generate a heatmap in python from a text file, using R commands (with rpy2). It works fine in R, but when I take it to python, the Quartz interface displays quickly and then closes. I would like either to be able to save the quartz display to a file, or directly save my heatmap to a file without displaying it.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects 

robjects.r('''
library("gplots")
data = read.csv("/Users/.../Heatmap_data.txt")
DF = data.frame(data)
MD = data.matrix(DF,rownames.force=NA)
heatmap.2(MD, scale="none", col=redgreen(100), cexRow=0.1, key=FALSE, symkey=FALSE, trace="none", Colv=FALSE)
''')
```

I'm using python 2.7, on OS X Yosemite.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
ro.numpy2ri.activate() 
R = ro.r

data = np.random.random((10, 10))
R.png(file='/tmp/out.png')
R.heatmap(data)
R("dev.off()")
```

[writes to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/190597) `/tmp/out.png` without displaying the image:

[image].

---

[Preventing the displayed image from immediately closing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12655771/190597) can be done like this:

script.py:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
import time
import threading

ro.numpy2ri.activate() 
R = ro.r

def ion():
    def r_refresh(interval = 0.03):
        while True:
            rinterface.process_revents()
            time.sleep(interval)
    t = threading.Thread(target=r_refresh)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

ion()
data = np.random.random((10, 10))
R.heatmap(data)

R("dev.copy(png,'/tmp/out2.png')")
R("dev.off()")
try:
    # for Python2
    raw_input()
except NameError:
    # for Python3
    input()
```

The `raw_input` or `input` call prevents the Python interpreter from exiting, thus allowing the window to stay open, until the user presses Enter.

The `ion` function [calls `rinterface.process_revents()` periodically](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/rinterface.html#processing-interactive-events) so the
displayed window will react to GUI events such as resizing or being closed.

`dev.copy(png,'/tmp/out2.png')` [saves the already-displayed image to a
file](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/saving.html).